# SQL Server If statement to update table value

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, sql-update

I'm trying  write a routine in SQL Server that, when run, would traverse specified tables and, if a specific column contains a value, update another value. In pseudo code:

```
 select * from table1
 if column1 = true
 {
     update table2.column1 with value where table2.column2.value = table1.column2.value
 }
```

Basically, traverse `table1` and if the value in a specific column is true, update the value of another table's `column1` where that row's `column2` matches `table1`'s `column2`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `IF`, just use a `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE T2
SET t2.Column1 = 'blah'
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1
   ON t1.value = t2.value
WHERE t1.column1 = 'True'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand your requirement, but if you want update all the values using a single update statement this might do:

```
update table2 set column1 = 
       (select column1 from table1 t1 
        where  t1.column2 = table2.column2
       )
    where exists 
       (select *  from table1 t1 
        where t1.column2 = table2.column2 and t1.column1 = true
       )
```

It could be written to avoid having the 2nd subselect (the EXISTS clause) but the solution is rather dialect-specific.  This one is, I believe, more likely to be accepted in an unknown dialect. (Except for the word "true" ... substitute the value you want, there. )